# C# как динамически указывать путь к папке с файлами

Tags: c#, winforms

В C# WinForms хочется указать стандартный выбор каталога откуда будут считываться файлы. Хочется что-бы было похоже на указание пути установки программы.

Что необходимо: есть кнопка вызывающая проводник, а когда ты указываешь в ней нужный путь, он автоматически подтягивается в строку `TextBox`.

Comment: И в чем проблема? Вешает TextBox, а рядом кнопку. На кнопку вешаешь обработчик события, который открывает FileDialog, там выбирается файл, а затем это подсовываешь в свой TextBox.

Comment: [FolderBrowserDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делается это достаточно просто. Для примера, закидываем на форму компонент `Button` - кнопку, по клику на которую мы будем открывать диалог выбора папки и сам компонент выбора папки `FolderBrowserDialog`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого кликаем дважды по кнопке, автоматически создастся метод обработки клика на эту кнопку и добавим простой код обработки:

```
private string folderName; // тут будем хранить путь к папке

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // показать диалог выбора папки
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

    // если папка выбрана и нажата клавиша `OK` - значит можно получить путь к папке
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // запишем в нашу переменную путь к папке
        folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Собственно сама ссылка на документацию: [`FolderBrowserDialog`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2) там есть пример кода. Чтобы записать полученное значение в необходимый `TextBox` нужно просто добавить на форму элемент `TextBox` и вместо строки кода:

```
folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
```

Выполнить присвоение текста добавленному ранее `TextBox` через его свойство `Text` вот так:

```
textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
```

Еще пара ссылок:

- [TextBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [TextBox.Text Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_Text)

Answer (score 0):

Вот код для выбора папки:

```
using(var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{    
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
    {
         // вот выбранный путь, его можно потом засунуть в ваш textbox
         string path = fbd.SelectedPath;           
    }
}
```